# How to speed up to compute Rand Index

Tags: java

I run a clustering over million elements.

Then, I would like to compute [Rand Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) to evaluate the generated clusters.

I write the following code, but it takes a long time.

```
    int TP = 0;
    int TN = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double randIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size() - 1; i++) {
        count++;
        for (int j = i; j < elements.size(); j++) {
            if (clusters.get(elements.get(i)) == clusters.get(elements.get(j)) && classes.get(elements.get(i)).equals(classes.get(elements.get(j)))) {
                TP++;
            } else if (clusters.get(elements.get(i)) != clusters.get(elements.get(j)) && classes.get(elements.get(i).equals(classes.get(elements.get(j))) == false) {
                TN++;
            }
        }
    }
    randIndex = ((double) TP + (double) TN) / (double) count;

    System.out.println("rand index" + randIndex);
```

In the code, `HashMap clusters` and `classes` returns an id or name of the class to which for a given element belong.

Is there any better way to speed up computation of the Rand Index?

Comment: You could start by storing values in variables instead of reexecuting (for example) `clusters.get(elements.get(i))` at each iteration. Also, what is the type of elements? Please tell me it's not a LinkedList.

Comment: Thank you, the type of elements is ArrayList.